# Hide part of an email address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What's the best way to hide 4 characters before the @ sign of an email address using ruby eg

```
fakename@example.com = fake####@example.com
```

It's going to be used in a view when I display a list of testimonials and I don't want to display the whole address.

My long way round attempt:

```
name = 'fakename@example.com'.split("@")[0]
email = 'fakename@example.com'.split("@")[1]
new_address = name [0..-4] + "@" + email
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the below that will even handle short names like a@example.com

```
'fakename@example.com'.gsub(/.{0,4}@/, '####@')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'fakename@example.com'.gsub(/.{4}@/, '####@')
 => fake####@example.com
```

But it will not handle short names (a@example.com => a@example.com)

Comment: `'fakename@example.com'.gsub(/.{4}@/, '####@') == "fake####@example.com"` gives me `false`

Comment: @Salil: You are using a double quoted string. Double quoted strings perform string interpolation. `#@example` means "insert the contents of the instance variable `@example` at this point in the string". Since `@example` probably doesn't exist, it will evaluate to `nil`, so the final string you are comparing against will be `'fake###.com'`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag:- `"fakename@example.com".gsub(/.{4}@/, '####@') == "fake###\#@example.com"` gives me true

Answer (score 0):

you can use the the Regex to match and replace in the email address. just find for four consecutive characters followed by an @ and give the replace string as `####@` Regex in ruby are considered very very efficient.

use this Regex for the first match `/[a-z.]{4}@/`